# How to include image in jquery nestable

Tags: jquery, treeview

How to include image in jquery.nestable in expand/collapse button instead of (+/-)?

https://github.com/dbushell/Nestable

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at the demo, using [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) to inspect the CSS, reveals that you could probably edit this part of the CSS to manipulate how the (+/-) buttons look:

```
.dd-item > button:before {
    content: '+';
    /* ... */
}

.dd-item > button[data-action="collapse"]:before {
    content: "-";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I hava a css class which has image. I want to use this class in that div element. How to do this?

Comment: @adriya: Why not just replace the `content: ...` lines (quoted above) with `content: <img src="/path/to/your/image" />`?